Tao: Prove the Trichotomy of order for natural numbers
Let the universe be $\mathbb{N}$.

Theorem: For any $a$ and $b$ exactly one of these is true;
$a=b,a>b,a<b$

Here is a relevant definition

Definition 2.2.11 (Ordering of the natural numbers). Let $n$ and $m$
be natural numbers. We say that $n$ is greater than or equal to $m$,
and write $n\ge m$ or $m \le n$, if and only if, we have $n = m + a$
for some natural number $a$. We say that $n$ is strictly greater than
$m$, and write $n>m$ or $m<n$, if and only if $n\ge m$ and $n\neq m$.

My Proof: Let $a$ and $b$ be arbitrary. Either $a=b$ or $a\neq b$, suppose $a\neq b$ we claim $a<b~\oplus a>b$ (XOR). Suppose not so... $$a>b\Leftrightarrow  a<b\equiv a=b+m_1\Leftrightarrow b=a+m_2$$ where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are some positive numbers. The expression above implies $a=a+(m_1+m_2)$ wich is a contradiction. Now consider when both properties don't hold, that is for all positive numbers $m_1$ and $m_2$, $a\neq b+m_1$ and $b\neq a +m_2$. We insert the following lemma to derive a contradiction.
Lemma:For any $a$ and $b$ the statement $$(a=b)\vee (a>b)\vee (a<b)$$ is a tautology.
Proof: We induct on $b$ leaving $a$ fixed. $$P(0):0\le a$$ is true for every $a$. Now assume $P(b)$ holds consider $P(b++)$ (Where $b++$ denotes the successor of $b$). If $a\le b$ then $a<b++$, and if $a>b$ then $a\ge b++$. $W^4$
Now back to our original proof if $a\neq b+m_1$ and $b\neq a +m_2$ are both true, then by the Lemma $a=b$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $a<b~\oplus a>b$. Here is where I'm stuck. I feel like this "proof" is missing something, because I have shown that $a\neq b\Longrightarrow a<b~\oplus a>b $ but not necessarily $a<b~\oplus a>b\oplus~a=b$.  Any help would be appreciated.

You started your proof with $a=b \oplus a \neq b$, so it follows (your proof of $\implies$ is actually a proof of $\iff$)

It seems like this proof correctly shows that $a>b$ and $a<b$ can't be simultaneously true, but it doesn't show that they can't be simultaneously false (when $a\ne b$).

@GregMartin I belive, when $a\neq b$ my proof shows $a<b~\oplus~a>b$ is a tautology. The scenario where both $a>b$ and $a<b$ are false is covered in the reductio ad absurdum.

One cannot deduce $a=a+m_1+m_2$ if neither $m_1$ nor $m_2$ exist.

@GregMartin I understand, I have fixed the proof.
